# How could we iterate into List's elements without knowing its type?‽‽

Tags: java, database, jpa, persistence, crud

I am following this tutorial to learn how to use Java DB in a NetBeans CRUD app:
https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html

And I have reached the point where I need to run the application.

The question is: why the outputs says:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: javax.annotation.Generated
C:\Users\YonePC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DBManager\CustomerViewer\src\org\shop\viewer\CustomerViewerTopComponent.java:51: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        List<Customer> resultList = (List<Customer>) query.getResultList();
  required: List<Customer>
  found:    List
2 warnings
```

The code we are trying and where is the bug is:

```
public CustomerViewerTopComponent() {
        initComponents();
        setName(Bundle.CTL_CustomerViewerTopComponent());
        setToolTipText(Bundle.HINT_CustomerViewerTopComponent());
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CustomerLibraryPU").createEntityManager();
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll");
        List<Customer> resultList =  query.getResultList();
        for (Customer c : resultList) {
            jTextArea1.append(c.getName() + " (" + c.getCity() + ")" + "\n");
        }

    }
```

Customer is an entity class:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Integer customerId;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESSLINE1")
    private String addressline1;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESSLINE2")
    private String addressline2;
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "STATE")
    private String state;
    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "FAX")
    private String fax;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "CREDIT_LIMIT")
    private Integer creditLimit;
    @JoinColumn(name = "DISCOUNT_CODE", referencedColumnName = "DISCOUNT_CODE")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private DiscountCode discountCode;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ZIP", referencedColumnName = "ZIP_CODE")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private MicroMarket zip;

... getters and setters ...
```

I tryed the following:

```
public final class CustomerViewerTopComponent extends TopComponent {

    public CustomerViewerTopComponent() {
        initComponents();
        setName(Bundle.CTL_CustomerViewerTopComponent());
        setToolTipText(Bundle.HINT_CustomerViewerTopComponent());
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CustomerLibraryPU").createEntityManager();
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll");
        List<Customer> resultList = (List<Customer>) query.getResultList();
        for (Customer c : resultList) {
            jTextArea1.append(c.getName() + " (" + c.getCity() + ")" + "\n");
        }

    }
```

I tryed to cast the List, to match the given input as List String with the declared one: List String

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's a simple compiler warning. It's telling you that, at runtime, there won't be any check that the list is indeed a `List<Customer>`.

The proper way to suppress the warning is to use a `TypedQuery`, by calling 
[`createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll", Customer.class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-). That won't add any guarantee that the list indeed contains customers at runtime, but it will suppress the warning.

The main problems in your code, however, aren't spotted by the compiler: you shouldn't use EntityManager from a Swing component. This should be delegated to another object. And creating a new EntityManagerFactory every time you need to execute a query is really, really not a good idea. An EntityManagerFactory is a  heavyweight, thread-safe object. You should create it once and only once, and use it every where you need one.